# How do I fill primary key value via a form and php query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:**student** table with the following fields:

1. student_id (primary key)
2. firstname
3. lastname
4. email

And **score** table:

1. student_id (foreign key)
2. math
3. biology
4. physics

I want to insert into **score** table with a form with php.

I have retrieved form data and stored them in variables:

```
$math = $_POST ['math'];
$ biology = $_POST ['biology'];  
$ physics = $_POST ['physics'];
```

Now how do I write the query to insert these data into database?
I mean how d I fill value for field student_id which is a primary key.

What should I write instead of aaaa in the following query.

```
INSERT INTO score VALUES ('aaaa', '$  math', '$ biology', '$ physics');
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. You should retrieve `student_id` for current student somehow. It highly depends on your code structure.

Comment: primary key's should also have a auto_increment  this way you do don't have to use student_id column within your student insert query..  and you can use the last_insert_id as student_id column for the score table.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the `student_id` in a hidden field in your HTML and access it in your `$_POST`.

Just give the hidden field a name like `name="hiddenStudentId"` and it will appear under `$_POST["hiddenStudentId"]`

Comment: What if this hiddenStudentId doesnt match any student id in the student table?

Comment: This shouldn't happen because you have to provide the student_id from your database to the form. Let's say you click on a Student which opens a form where the hidden field is placed. Or you could make a select input with your students where the ID is stored in the value of the option

Comment: How can I provide student_id from database to the form??

Comment: I'm assuming that you have a html-list of your students which may be links to the form-page. You can add a `$_GET`-Variable to the links (<a>-Tags) like `<a href="link to studentScores.php?student_id=idFromDatabase">Student 1</a>`  In studentScores.php is a form with the hidden-field and its value is `value="<?= $_GET['student_id'] ?>`